# Serve precompiled JS file with changed ENV params depending on the request

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Inspired by the Google Maps API way of fetching JS file I would like to serve my clients a JS file with compiled ENV variable depending on their request parameters. I know that Google's way is for authentication only.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

So if my customer would use this in theirs HTML

```
<script src="https://myapi.com/api/js?myEnvVariable=VARIABLE_VALUE" async defer></script>
```

they would get a script that would contain this value built somewhere inside and effectively mimic the use of .env files.

```
var someValue = VARIABLE_VALUE;
```

What would be the best option to do that?

- Build separate JS file for each customer/parameter and then serve the right file
- Read JS as string, find & replace some placeholder with the requested parameter and return to user
- Use global `window.myEnvVariable=VARIABLE_VALUE` on client and do not complicate
- Some standard way I am not aware of :)

Any ideas?

Comment: why not rip the params from the script src and set vars inside the file from that? All from JS static code. I don't see a need to hard code such values and doing so complicates caching, increases server load, and lowers performance. Serving hard-coded user-supplied data could also introduce security issues from improper sanitization and escaping.

Comment: ex: for this page, reading the highlightjs's script tag's `v` value: `new URL($$("script[src*='highlightjs']")[0].src).searchParams.get("v");`